# Best practice in Python for accessing self in another Class

Tags: python, oop, object

For example if I have 2 classes `Tree` and `Node`, in the `add_node` method in `Tree`, I can add `self` referring to the `Tree` into the `Node` object as shown below. This is done for convenience when accessing other parts of the `Tree` with just the keys once in the `Node` object (i.e. can just use keys). However, I was wondering if this was considered best practice since the IDE (PyCharm) also screams `Unresolved attribute reference 'tree' for class 'Node'` so might be not a great sign as well.

```py
class Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.nodes = {}
    def add_node(self, count):
        new_node = Node()
        new_node.tree = self
        self.nodes[count] = new_node

class Node:
    def __init__(self):
        # Some data e.g. parent, children index
        pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass the tree in the initializer for the `Node`

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, tree):
        self.tree = tree
```

And when creating the node:

```
...
        new_node = Node(self)
        self.nodes[count] = new_node
...
```